# How to use variable outside the loop, after initializing inside the loop?

Tags: swift, loops, initialization, swift4

Want to code a function that will take an array of strings named straar and an integer named k. It will return k times longest strings merged together.

[image]

code:

```
import UIKit

func longestConsec( strarr: [String], k: Int) -> String {

    var strerr : [String] = Array()
    strerr = strarr
    var longest : Int
    longest = 0
    var longestString : String
    var finalBoss : String
    finalBoss = ""

    for v in 1...k{
        for long in strerr{

            if (long.count > longest){                  

                longest = long.count
                longestString = long
            }                
        }         

        finalBoss += longestString
        for lang in 0...strerr.count{                
            if (strerr[lang] == longestString){                    
                strerr.remove(at:lang)                    
            }                
        }            
    }
    return finalBoss
}
```

Comment: The error messages are extremely clear. What do you not understand? Perhaps instead of `var longestString : String` you mean `var longestString = ""`.

Comment: I want to use the information I recieved through longestString = long. I want to use the last biggest "long" after the loop finished.

Comment: Fine, but what you asked about seemed to be the compile error. I told you what to do to make the error go away.

Comment: Both longest and longestString are declared outside the loop so they can be used after the loop. I fail to see the problem (apart from your compilation errors)

Answer (score 0):

there are some problem with the code. The var 'longestString' needs to be initialized before being used. And in the last for loop fails because the index is mayor than the count of items. Here's the code with some corrections.

```
func longestConsec( strarr: [String], k: Int) -> String {

var strerr = strarr
var longest : Int
longest = 0
var longestString : String = ""
var finalBoss : String
finalBoss = ""

for _ in 1...k {

    for long in strerr {

        if (long.count > longest) {

            longest = long.count
            longestString = long
        }
    }

    finalBoss += longestString

    for lang in 1 ..< strerr.count {

        if (strerr[lang] == longestString) {
            strerr.remove(at:lang)
        }
    }
}

print("finalBoss: \(finalBoss)")

return finalBoss
```

}

longestConsec(strarr: ["Eleven", "Two", "Three"], k: 3)